# Survey of Consumer Finances - What counts as a family?

Tags: central-banking, definition, united-states

I am looking at the Federal Reserves survey of consumer finances. I am wondering what counts as a family? For example, would a single person living alone count as a family?
What about an adult son living with his parents? Would that be one family or two?

Comment: https://www.federalreserve.gov/publications/files/scf20.pdf - Definition of “Family” in the Survey of Consumer Finances

Comment: @AKdemy I read the appendix where it attempts to define a family. However, the definition is still unclear to me. I now believe that a single person living alone counts as a family. What about an adult son living with his parents? Is that one family or two? I am thinking it is one.

Comment: A family can be a single person or couple and everyone financially interdependent with that single person or couple. Therefore, your reasoning is correct.